# Why is $\text{Exterior}(A) = \text{int}(A^c) = \text{cl}(A)^c$?

Tags: general-topology

Why is $\text{Exterior}(A) = \text{int}(A^c) = \text{cl}(A)^c$?

I'm having difficulties proving $\text{int}(A^c) = \text{cl}(A)^c$

Comment: How do you define $A^°$ and $\bar A$?

Comment: The order of your closure, interiors, and complements is difficult to read.  Some parentheses would be helpful.  $(A^c)^\circ=(\overline{A})^c$.

Comment: @martini Usually $A^\circ$ is the interior of $A$ and $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Sure. But there are different definitions of closure and interior out there, so I asked.

Comment: @martini Sorry, there were two possible questions you were asking, and I guessed the wrong one.

Comment: @MichaelBurr No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{int}(A^c)$ can be classified as "largest open subset" of $A^c$. It is the union of all open subsets of $A^c$, hence is open itself.

> Essential statement: the complement of this set is automatically the smallest closed set that contains $A$ as a subset.

$\text{cl}(A)$ can be classified as "smallest closed set that has $A$ as a subset". It is the intersection of all closed sets that have $A$ as a subset, hence is closed itself.

So actually we stated that:$$\text{int}(A^c)^c=\text{cl}(A)$$

Which is equivalent with:$$\text{int}(A^c)=\text{cl}(A)^c$$

Comment: thanks, that's the right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You prove this in the normal way by showing one set is a subset of another.  I will illustrate with one direction:

Suppose that $x\in(A^c)^\circ$.  Since $x$ is in the interior of $A^c$, there is an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\subseteq A^c$.  Therefore, $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ that does intersect $A$.  Therefore, $x$ is not in the closure of $A$, i.e., $x\not\in\overline{A}$.  Hence, $x\in(\overline{A})^c$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathrm{cl}(A)^c = \left(\bigcap_{\substack{V\text { closed} \\ A \subset V}} V\right)^c = \left(\bigcap_{\substack{U\text { open} \\ A \subset U^c}} U^c\right)^c = \bigcup_{\substack{U\text { open} \\ A \subset U^c}} U = \bigcup_{\substack{U\text { open} \\ U \subset A^c}} U = \mathrm{int}(A^c)
$$